# What is word used to describe someone who is very kind and likes most to help other people with their problems?

Tags: single-word-requests

I would like to ask this question; A word that is used to describe someone who is very kind and likes most to help other people with their problems?
(I need both a noun and an adjective; if they are all applied)

Comment: Please include the research you've done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Comment: *altruist*, *altruistic*

Comment: Thank you for explaining the part of speech of the words you are looking for; it's helpful. However, you should edit your question, because it currently is missing important information. Please explain the context in which you would like to use these words (an example sentence with a blank space is a good way of doing this) and elaborate on what you mean by "if they are all applied." To learn more about asking "single word requests" on this site, you should read the [tag information](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info).

Comment: @Drew Are altruists necessarily kind? I think that only gets the "helps other people" criteria. You could be an altruist who gives money to people because it looks good but who has a mean or cruel personality.

Comment: @Hack-R: They are not necessarily kind. But they don't do it because if looks good - that's not altruism. Kindness and altruism are not the same thing, but both involve *unselfish concern for others*. WordWeb definition: *altruism: The quality of unselfish concern for the welfare of others.* Kindness generally includes altruism, but not necessarily vice versa.

Answer (score 6):

An **altruist:**

> a person unselfishly concerned for or devoted to the welfare of others (opposed to egoist ). 
>   http://www.dictionary.com/browse/altruist

The adjectival form is *altrusitic.*

"She is very *altrusitic,* her greatest joy is to help out a friend in need."

Comment: This is particularly appropriate if the individual disregards personal harm for the sake of helping others.

Answer (score 3):

"good samaritan" comes to  mind - Someone who helps another in need for compassionate motives and with no thought of reward.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parable_of_the_Good_Samaritan

Comment: I would use this for a person that feels compelled to help others out of moral or ethical obligation.

Answer (score 2):

I would choose ***benevolent*** (noun form ***benefactor***) to describe a kind and giving person.

> :  marked by or disposed to doing good <*a benevolent donor*>
>   
> [<sub>Merriam-Webster</sub>](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/benevolent)